# Why my property do not change dynamically?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class like this:

```
open class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String) {

var fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
    get() = "Name: $field"
    set(value){
        if(value.startsWith("Jon")){
            field = "Jon Doe"
        }else{
            field = value
        }
    }
}
```

Why `fullName`does not change if I change the `firstName` like:

```
val person1 = User("Mark", "Zuck")

println(person1.fullName)
//Mark Zuck

person1.firstName = "Bill"

println(person1.firstName)
//Bill

println(person1.fullName)
//Mark Zuck

person1.lastName = "Gates"

println(person1.fullName)
//prints Mark Zuck
```

Is it because `fullName` are bounded by getters and setters that's why the only way to change it is by accessing `fullname` directly???

Comment: Try `val fullName; get() = "$firstName $lastName"`. You don't need a backing field.

Comment: @Jorn your code works but I don't know what's happening

Comment: My example simply makes a property that's only a getter - calculated on access every time you call it.

Comment: @Jorn Oh I get it, `fullName` does not change because when I typed `get() = "Name: $field"` it just return what has been initialize during the instantiation, and now I've changed it to `get() = "$firstName $lastName"` so it calculates again and return the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

when we say

```
get() = "Name: $field"
```

it just return the value that have been initialize during the instantiation, to fix that I just change it to

```
get() = "$firstName $lastName"
```

so that it calculates again and return the updated value

full code:

```
var fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
    get() = "$firstName $lastName"
    set(value){
        field = value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this: [Getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters) - basically because you're referring to `field` in your getter (and the setter), there's a *backing field* storing a value. And your *getter* (which is a function) is reading from that backing field when it calculates a value to return.

The code you posted as an answer:

```
var fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
    get() = "$firstName $lastName"
    set(value){
        field = value
    }
```

is pretty much equivalent to this:

`val fullName get() = "$firstName $lastName"`

because your *getter* never references the *backing field*. Your *setter* really does nothing - it stores the value you pass in the backing field, but that field is never read. If you remove the reference to the backing field:

```
var fullName
    get() = "$firstName $lastName"
    set(value){ }
```

then *no backing field is created*, because your *getter* and *setter* both do their own thing without involving the field. So you don't need to initialise it with a value - there's no field to initialise! The *getter* was never using it anyway.

And since your *setter* does nothing, you may as well delete it and make your property a `val` since you could never (directly) change its value anyway - `fullName = "Some Guy"` had no visible effect, so making it a `var` is pretty misleading!

And that's how you end up with a simple getter that returns a value derived from other properties:

`val fullName get() = "$firstName $lastName"`

---

If you wanted, you *could* make that *setter* update `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
var fullName
    get() = "$firstName $lastName"
    set(value){
        // you'd need to handle the possible errors here
        val names = value.split(' ')
        firstName = names[0]
        lastName = names[1]
    }
```

Again that's not using a *backing field*, the data is stored somewhere else (in `firstName` and `lastName` in this case) and the *getter* and *setter* are just functions that handle storing and retrieving the data in some form. This is just an example, you probably wouldn't want to do this here (updating `firstName` and `lastName` directly is way better and less work to handle) but this is just to show you *could*! Sometimes you do this kind of thing with a *setter*

Comment: why typing `var fullName = "$firstName $lastName"` does not update its values whenever I change the `firstName` like `firstName = "someGuy` why is it that we need to add `get` to it @cactustictacs

Comment: @JamesGosling `var thing = whatever` is just assigning a value to `thing`. So when you declare `var fullName = "$firstName $lastName"` at some point in your code, it reads the *current values* of `firstName` and `lastName`, whatever they are *at the moment that code runs*, creates a `String` from that, and then assigns it to `fullName`. That value won't change until you assign another value with `fullName = "something else"`.

Comment: But using `get()` makes it a *getter* (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters) - it's not a stored *value* anymore, it's a *function* that actually runs every time you read from that property. So *every time* you read `fullName`, it gets the *current value* of `firstName` and `lastName` and builds a new string. It's like what happened when you assigned a value in the first example, except here it runs *every time the property is accessed* so you always get an up-to-date string based off the current values. It's like writing `fun getCurrentName() { // make string }`